# Is there a fix for "TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments" when creating a Button with Kivy?

Tags: python, button, kivy, init, keyword-argument

When I used a button before, passing `**kwargs` to `object.__init__()` worked just fine. After adding a Button in my grid it now displays this error.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\trist\.kivy\logs\kivy_20-10-15_0.txt
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.gstreamer" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.angle" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.glew" 0.3.0
[INFO   ] [deps        ] Successfully imported "kivy_deps.sdl2" 0.3.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v1.11.1
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "C:\Users\trist\PycharmProjects\AndroisOS\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.0 (v3.7.0:1bf9cc5093, Jun 27 2018, 04:06:47) [MSC v.1914 32 bit (Intel)]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "C:\Users\trist\PycharmProjects\AndroisOS\venv\Scripts\python.exe"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 184 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_gif (img_pil, img_ffpyplayer ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] GLEW initialization succeeded
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <glew>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'4.6.0 - Build 26.20.100.7263'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Intel(R) HD Graphics 530'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 4, 6
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'4.60 - Build 26.20.100.7263'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <32>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/trist/PycharmProjects/AndroisOS/main.py", line 47, in <module>
    MyApp().run()
  File "C:\Users\trist\PycharmProjects\AndroisOS\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\app.py", line 829, in run
    root = self.build()
  File "C:/Users/trist/PycharmProjects/AndroisOS/main.py", line 38, in build
    return MyGrid()
  File "C:/Users/trist/PycharmProjects/AndroisOS/main.py", line 32, in __init__
    self.submit = Button(text="Next", fontsize=40)
  File "C:\Users\trist\PycharmProjects\AndroisOS\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\behaviors\button.py", line 121, in __init__
    super(ButtonBehavior, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trist\PycharmProjects\AndroisOS\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\label.py", line 318, in __init__
    super(Label, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\trist\PycharmProjects\AndroisOS\venv\lib\site-packages\kivy\uix\widget.py", line 350, in __init__
    super(Widget, self).__init__(**kwargs)
  File "kivy\_event.pyx", line 243, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.__init__
TypeError: object.__init__() takes no arguments

Process finished with exit code 1
```

I get this error from the file which looks like so(with my problem only occurring once I use the Button.):

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.textinput import TextInput
from kivy.uix.button import Button

class MyGrid(GridLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyGrid, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.cols = 1

self.add_widget(Label(text="What is your EAVE/PURLIN width?"))
self.metal = TextInput(multiline=False)
self.add_widget(self.metal)
        
self.submit = Button(text="Next", fontsize=40)
self.add_widget(self.submit)

class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyGrid()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyApp().run()
```

Comment: Please post the complete error message including back trace.

Comment: I have just edited it, my desired function is simple, display a text, textbox, and a button. Could you please reopen and not close my question again?

Comment: Hi Tristan, welcome to the site. Your edit looks good, though that's a really confusing error message (Kivy's fault, not yours). I looks like you've used the wrong argument name for the size of font to use on your button. Try [`font_size=40`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.font_size) instead of `fontsize=40`.

Comment: Basically I've narrowed it down to, once I type in 
self.submit = Button(text="Next", fontsize=40)
self.add_widget(self.submit)
there is an error with the object.init()
before that it would accept the **kwargs I passed through it.

Comment: NO WAY! MAN. I was following yt tutorial too. Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do I mark this as answered?

Comment: "*How do I mark this as answered?*" Currently you can't because it's closed. But since it's going through the reopen queue now, you could wait if/until your question gets reopened, to let people post an answer (or [post one yourself](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer)). Then, [mark one of the answers as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are passing the wrong argument to the `Button` constructor. It expects the font size to be specified by a [`font_size`](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.font_size) parameter, but you're using `fontsize` without the underscore. Try:

```
self.submit = Button(text="Next", font_size=40)
```

Normally when you call a function with an incorrect argument you'll get a more helpful error message. It's a minor failing of Kivy that it's error message in this situation is so useless.